# How to Post Form Data using Material-UI into API

Tags: reactjs, rest, post, material-ui

I have a POST API which requires a request body in this form :

```
 {
        "module_id": 7,
        "module_type": "Post-Reading",
        "module_name": "Course Overview",
        "duration": 70,
 }
```

Now below is my React Code, I am unable to proceed as in how to send the request body.
Also, I want to update the module_id serially.
Can someone please help with that. I know there are a lot of errors, please help in rectifying.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import NativeSelect from '@material-ui/core/NativeSelect';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Timeline from '@material-ui/lab/Timeline';
import TimelineItem from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineItem';
import TimelineSeparator from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineSeparator';
import TimelineConnector from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineConnector';
import TimelineContent from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineContent';
import TimelineOppositeContent from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineOppositeContent';
import TimelineDot from '@material-ui/lab/TimelineDot';
import FastfoodIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Fastfood';
import LaptopMacIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LaptopMac';
import HotelIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Hotel';
import RepeatIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Repeat';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import axios from 'axios';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        minWidth: 120,
    },
    selectEmpty: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
}));

const NewModule = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [state, setState] = useState({});
    const [moduleid, setModuleId] = useState(0);
    const [moduletype, setModuleType] = useState("");
    const [modulename, setModuleName] = useState("");
    const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);

    const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8083/getmoduletypes")
            .then(res => {
                setDropdown(res.data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }, []);
const handleDropdownChange = (event) => {
        const name = event.target.name;
        setDropdown({
            ...dropdown,
            [name]: event.target.value,
        });
    };
    const handleChangeModuleType = (event) => {
        const name = event.target.name;
        setModuleType({
            ...moduletype,
            [name]: event.target.value,
        });
    };
    const handleChangeDuration = (event) => {
        const name = event.target.name;
        setDuration({
            ...duration,
            [name]: event.target.value,
        });
    };
    state = {moduleid, moduletype, modulename, duration};
    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post("http://localhost:8083/createmodule", state)
        .then( response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
        console.log(moduletype);
    }
    return (
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" style={{ width: "350px", marginTop: "20px", marginLeft: "30px", height: "450px" }}>
                <div>
                    <Icon color="primary"><b>+ Add New Module</b></Icon>
                </div>
                <FormControl variant="outlined" onSubmit={submitHandler }>
                    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label" >Choose Module Type</InputLabel>
                    <Select
                        labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
                        id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
                        onChange={() => handleDropdownChange}
                        label="TypeList"
                    >
                        {
                            dropdown.map(options =>
                            <MenuItem value={options["module_type"]} >{options["module_type"]}</MenuItem>
                        )}
                    </Select>


                    <TextField
                        style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
                        id="outlined-helperText"
                        label="Module Name"
                        onChange={handleChangeModuleType}
                        variant="outlined"
                    />
                    <TextField
                        style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
                        id="outlined-helperText"
                        label="Course Duration"
                        onChange={handleChangeDuration}
                        variant="outlined"
                    />
                    <div style={{ margin: "auto", marginTop: "20px" }}>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >ADD</button>

                    </div>
                </FormControl>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
export default NewModule;
```

Please let me know how to post data in the same format also is the onChangeHandlers correct for everything.

Thank you!

Comment: Did my answer help get you on the right path?

Answer (score 2):

You want to encapsulate your components in a form element, like this, and then define a handleSubmit function (or whatever you might want to call it)

In your handleSubmit you can then use fetch to send your form data to your API in whatever format you want. I usually take my data and use JSON.stringify() to turn it into a JSON string, similar to what your requirements appear to be.

```
    return (
    <div class="container">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div class="row" style={{ width: "350px", marginTop: "20px", marginLeft: "30px", height: "450px" }}>
            <div>
                <Icon color="primary"><b>+ Add New Module</b></Icon>
            </div>
            <FormControl variant="outlined" onSubmit={submitHandler }>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label" >Choose Module Type</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
                    id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
                    onChange={() => handleDropdownChange}
                    label="TypeList"
                >
                    {
                        dropdown.map(options =>
                        <MenuItem value={options["module_type"]} >{options["module_type"]}</MenuItem>
                    )}
                </Select>


                <TextField
                    style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
                    id="outlined-helperText"
                    label="Module Name"
                    onChange={handleChangeModuleType}
                    variant="outlined"
                />
                <TextField
                    style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
                    id="outlined-helperText"
                    label="Course Duration"
                    onChange={handleChangeDuration}
                    variant="outlined"
                />
                <div style={{ margin: "auto", marginTop: "20px" }}>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >ADD</button>

                </div>
            </FormControl>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

)
```

}